# Silverstripe Pagination over a subclass of Page

Tags: php, pagination, content-management-system, silverstripe

I've created a page subclass, which works just fine, of course.  But when I try to use the pagination class to go over pages of that type, the documented code doesn't output anything.  Using the pagination class and template info here:

```
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/howto/pagination
```

I can loop over my subpage:

```
public function PaginatedPages() {
    return new PaginatedList(Page::get(), $this->request);
}
```

Modified to use the subclass instead:

```
public function PaginatedPages() {
    return new PaginatedList(ReportPage::get(), $this->request);
}
```

With this in the template:

```
<ul>
    <% loop $PaginatedPages %>
        <li><a href="$Link">$Title</a></li>
    <% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

That loops fine.  But if I try to use the more robust pagination code in the template:

```
<% if $PaginatedPages.MoreThanOnePage %>
    <% if $PaginatedPages.NotFirstPage %>
        <a class="prev" href="$PaginatedPages.PrevLink">Prev</a>
    <% end_if %>
    <% loop $PaginatedPages.Pages %>
        <% if $CurrentBool %>
            $PageNum
        <% else %>
            <% if $Link %>
                <a href="$Link">$PageNum</a>
            <% else %>
                ...
            <% end_if %>
        <% end_if %>
        <% end_loop %>
    <% if $PaginatedPages.NotLastPage %>
        <a class="next" href="$PaginatedPages.NextLink">Next</a>
    <% end_if %>
<% end_if %>
```

There is no output for that type of pagination.  Of course, this does work if I'm only using the original `PaginatedPage()` method with `Page::get()` but that's pretty useless for me.

Am I missing something here?  Is this pagination class just supposed to be for paginating over embedded lists of objects, and not creating a menu for actual pages?

Comment: Your second example is still using `Page::get()` and do you have more than 10 instances of your subclass?

Comment: @simon_w Ah, whoops, corrected, `ReportPage::get()` is what I meant.  I don't have more than ten instances of these pages, but I was hoping that it would work for both the cases of less than ten and more than ten, of course.  I don't really see why the loops wouldn't.

Comment: @simon_w I can add more pages, of course, though I'm not sure why that would make the navigation actually show up.

Comment: If you have only enough ReportPages for one paginated page, pagination will not display as you are calling `<% if $PaginatedPages.MoreThanOnePage %>`. This checks if there is more than one pagination page. If you want the pagination to show up even when there is only 1 pagination page change the if statement to `<% if $PaginatedPages %>`. Although personally I would not want to display pagination if there is only 1 page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test with few pages (eg. 5 per page) you can modify your PaginatedPages function like the following:

```
public function PaginatedPages($n = 10) {
    $pl = new PaginatedList(ReportPage::get(), $this->request);
    $pl->setPageLength($n);
    return $pl;
}
```

And then you can call it from the template modifying each occurrence of $PaginatedPages with $PaginatedPages(5). Your problem, as simon_w stated in the comment, is that you don't have enough pages to activate the pagination.